# show that $a{ \left\| x \right\| }_{ 1 }\le { \left\| x \right\| }_{ 2 }\le b{ \left\| x \right\| }_{ 1 }$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

show that there exist positive numbers a,b such that

$a{ \left\| x \right\|  }_{ 1 }\le { \left\| x \right\|  }_{ 2 }\le b{ \left\| x \right\|  }_{ 1 } $ for all $x\in { R }^{ N }$

Find the largest constant $a$ and the smallest constant $b$ with this property

I apply cauchy inequality (${ \left| { x }_{ 1 } \right|  }^{ 2 }+{ \left| { x }_{ 2 } \right|  }^{ 2 }+...+{ \left| { x }_{ n } \right|  }^{ 2 })(1+1+...+1)\ge { ({ \left| { x }_{ 1 } \right| +\left| { x }_{ 2 } \right| +...+\left| { x }_{ n } \right|  }) }^{ 2 }$

hence ${ \left\| x \right\|  }_{ 2 }\ge \frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { n }  } { \left\| x \right\|  }_{ 1 }$

however,i don't konw how to show $\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { n }  } $ is largest constant and i have no idea to find smallest constant $b$ with this property

any helps? thanks

Comment: Maybe you can remove the tag of set theory and add real analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $$||x||_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \leq \sqrt{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|\right)^2} = ||x||_1$$ so $b=1$ works. Now since $$||(1,0,0,\ldots, 0)||_1 = ||(1,0,0,\ldots, 0)||_2$$ we get that $b=1$ is the smallest possible value.

Comment: thank you,your solution is clear

Answer (score 3):

Applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

$$||x||_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|\leq\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}|x_i|^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1)}=\sqrt{n}||x||_2.$$

We have equality if $x_i = c$ for all $i$ -- so this is the tightest inequality.

$$\inf_{x \,\,\in \,\,\mathbf{R}^n \setminus \{0\}}\frac{||x||_2}{||x||_1}= \frac1{\sqrt{n}},$$

and $a = 1/\sqrt{n}$ is largest.

Comment: @potato: You're welcome